# Push only values to array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `PHP 7.4.1`.

When I am running:

```
<?php

$valArr = array();

$companyArr = array(
    'name' => '',
    'description' => '',
);
array_push($valArr,$companyArr);


$priceArr = array(
    'currentPrice' => '',
    'exch_name' => '',
    'exch_symbol' => '',
);
array_push($valArr,$priceArr);


$otherTrxArr = array(
    'otherTrx' => '',
);
array_push($valArr,$otherTrxArr);

print_r($valArr);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [description] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [currentPrice] => 
            [exch_name] => 
            [exch_symbol] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [otherTrx] => 
        )

)
```

However, I would only like to get:

```
Array
(
            [name] => 
            [description] => 
            [currentPrice] => 
            [exch_name] => 
            [exch_symbol] => 
            [otherTrx] => 
)
```

Any suggestions how to use the `array_push()` correctly to only add the values in the new array?

Comment: Use array_merge instead. https://3v4l.org/3e15Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not `array_push()`, it is doing what you asked of it, instead use `array_merge()`

```
$valArr = array();

$companyArr = array(
    'name' => '',
    'description' => '',
);

$priceArr = array(
    'currentPrice' => '',
    'exch_name' => '',
    'exch_symbol' => '',
);

$otherTrxArr = array(
    'otherTrx' => '',
);

$valArr = array_merge($companyArr, $priceArr, $otherTrxArr);
print_r($valArr);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [description] => 
    [currentPrice] => 
    [exch_name] => 
    [exch_symbol] => 
    [otherTrx] => 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `+` to merge arrays.
I don't use it myself since I find it confusing with `+` when you use arrays.
But it's possible and a few characters less.

```
$valArr = $companyArr + $priceArr + $otherTrxArr;
```

https://3v4l.org/R6EFO